# Mongoose Updating Certain Fields of a Document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to implement an update method for our API and I'm kinda new to the Node so I didn't know what would be the best practice to carry out the task of updating some fields of a document. Let me elaborate, we have a user model which keeps basic info of a user like name, age, sex, school, bio, birthday etc. Our update method should work as this, the request of the method includes the new values of the fields provided such as      {bio:'newBio'}        or        {school:'newSchool', name:'newName'}      I must update the provided fields with the provided data and leave the rest as they are. I was wondering what the best approach to the problem at hand would be. Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends on the database you are using to store the user data. Which database you are planning to use?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach what i can think of is to use $Set to perform the update operations.

an example would be :

```
var updatedUsers= function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('users').updateMany(
      { "_id": "value"},
      {
        $set: { bio: "new bio" }
      }
      ,
      function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        callback();
   });
};
```

and invoke your above function as :

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  updatedUsers(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: the "$set": {bio: "new bio"} looks pretty good for a single field but how can I update an entire object like {"firstName" : "the", "lastName:" "pirateapp"}